# Rally v2.0 Warning "It is no longer necessary to append \".js\" to WSAPI resources"

Tags: rally

Since upgrading to Rally v2.0 I've been repeatedly getting the following warning "It is no longer necessary to append \".js\" to WSAPI resources." (No errors).

Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In what circumstances do you get this warning?

For a general case, e.g. a browser, browser REST client, the answer is not append .js to the endpoints. For example:

```
https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/1.43/defect/2222.js?rankAbove=/defect/3333.js&fetch=Name,FormattedID,Rank
```

becomes

```
https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/defect/2222?rankAbove=/defect/3333.js&fetch=Name,FormattedID,Rank
```

But I saw this warning when using java toolkit, when using v2.0 and '.js' was not appended anywhere.

```
String[] warningList;
warningList = createResponse.getWarnings();
for (int w = 0; w < warningList.length; w++){
    System.out.println(warningList[w]);
}
```

I submitted a bug.

Comment: How can I make sure that it doesnt appends .js to the endpoints?
 
`var request = new Request("HierarchicalRequirement")`
`var queryResult = restApi.Query(request);`